# Why is $\,0\cdot\infty\,$ undefined?

Tags: linear-algebra, infinity

So, I was going through some calculus videos, and what I found was that it said that $\,0\cdot\infty\,$ is undefined. I'm confused why. Like, from an intuition stand point, it is obsviously $0$. Multiplication is simply repeated addition, and let's look at both sides. Let's say we are adding $\infty$ $0$ times to itself, the result is obviously $0$, as there is nothing to add, and it's simply blank, which means it's $0$. Let's take it the other way around, adding $0$ to itself an infinite number of times. This will again be $0$, as no matter how many you add $0$s together, it'll always remain $0$. So it clearly seems to be $0$, but why is it left undefined then?

Comment: Why is it obviously $0$?  Consider $f(x)=\frac 1x$ and $g(x)=x^2$.  Then $f(x)\to 0$ for large $x$ and $g(x)\to \infty$.  But $f(x)\times g(x)\to \infty$, not $0$.

Comment: It's probably talking about limits.

Comment: @lulu but functions aside, from taking the basic understandings of multiplication, it feels clearly 0.

Comment: $\infty$ is no number, you cannot multiply it with $0$.

Comment: The question only makes sense in the context of limits.

Comment: @Peter Even if infinity is no number, multiplication is simply repeated addition, so it basically means 0 added infinitely, and that would clearly be 0, yes?

Comment: A line has an infinite set of points, all of lemgth zero.  What is its lemgth ?

Comment: @Empy2 Wait, you're right. I got what you mean. Now I see why it's a contradiction. Sorry for the annoyance, and thank you for the explanation.

Comment: The infinite sum of zeros is $0$ because of the definition of the limit. Since every (finite) partial sum is $0$, the limit is $0$. However, we cannot actually add infinite many zeros.

Comment: There is no real flaw with your logic, with the only exception that $\infty$ is not a number and therefore the usual addition and multiplication laws may not behave the same as they do for natural numbers. In practice, $\infty\cdot 0$ is undefined because the convention is not to define it. There are reasons behind this that are just as good as your reason for $\infty\cdot 0 = 0$, but at the end of the day its a question about the conventions.

Comment: I've taken classes in real analysis where it's taken to be equal to $0$, and many more where it's undefined for reasons like lulu said.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for clearing up my doubt.